# Difference between handler and Scheduler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, scheduler

### I am trying to Understand the difference between `Handler` & `Scheduler`

---

**What I know**::

---

**`IN - JAVA(Not Android)`**

1. `Java` uses `JVM`
2. In Java `Scheduler` takes care of switching the control back and forth
   between `main-thread` and the `worker-threads`
3. It quickly happens and so its called `multi-threading`.
4. The developer has no access to `scheduler` and only he can influence
   the `scheduler`, `JVM` takes care of `scheduler` functionality

---

**`IN - ANDROID`**

1. `Android` uses `JVM`
2. A `scheduler` is called a `Handler` in android
3. Advantage is that developer has access to `Handler` through which he
   can control the `scheduling` of `threads`

---

**My Questions**::

1. Are my explanations correct ?
2. Are both handler and scheduler functionality wise the same ?
3. If my explanations are not correct what are the difference between
   `Handler` and `scheduler` ?
4. Advantages of using `handler` in android w.r.t `Scheduler` in Java ?

---

**Thanks** !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe your expansions are correct and the two are pretty different.
Android is a Java machine and still have a scheduler not accessible to the developer.

Handler holds the "handle" of one specific thread. To the Looper of the thread to be more specific (so only threads that "loops" may have handlers).

The handler allows the developer to request some code to be processed in a specific thread either as soon as possible (using the post method) or after some time (using the postDelayed method).

Note that the methods are called 'post'. That means the code will be posted to the scheduler and the scheduler will actually run the code on the requested thread whenever it is time for that thread to be execute.

PS. I answer that from my mobile, sorry for any misspellings.

Comment: @ Budius ..... [+1] for info .... So all handler does is like:: If a thread is responsible to post message ..... Using handler instance the developer can make the thread to loop(similarly to sleep ) and then perform the posting of the message ... but in-turn the scheduler executes this thread ! - correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: Yes n No. The thread have to be pre-prepared to loop (no sleep). If you call new Handler() inside a normal new Thread.run() the system will trow an exception. Check the LooperThread class on the docs. That type of thread can handle messages/runnables being posted to them via handler and the UI thread is of that type.